# Is it OK to create idioms similar to "brothers in arms"?

Tags: idiom-request, semantics

I know what "Brothers in arms" means. Can I use this idiom to get another idea across like "Brothers in mind/minds" to mean that they think similarly and of the same intellectual level?

Comment: You can't 'create' an idiom. Idioms are widely known and used expressions.

Comment: But someone creates them anyway.

Comment: You can, of course, create a new figure of speech; people do that all the time. Whether it develops into a widely used idiom is not something you can control.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps, but don't expect everyone to get what you mean unless you explain it.

"Brothers in arms" means you fought alongside each other (it doesn't mean just you have similar physical abilities) so "Brothers in mind" might mean you competed alongside each other, to a common goal, in some mental activity. It couldn't mean just "similar mental ability"

> John and I have been on the same quiz team for 10 years.  We have been "brothers in mind" at pubs from Lands End to John O'Groats.

Notice the use of *context* to help understand the meaning, and *scare quotes* to warn the reader that this is a new term.

I don't think this is a very good idea. It doesn't help your writing be clearer.

Comment: How would you convey the idea otherwise?

Comment: "We think similarly". "We are at a similar intellectual level".  Or with a little irony "Great minds think alike."